# Illegal indirection in C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, indirection

I got a template class and once it gets a `string` as a `T` and the other `Para*` as a `T`.
I have overloaded `<<` for `Para`.

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &wyjscie, Para const& ex){
        wyjscie << "(" << ex.wrt << ", " << ex.liczbaWystapien <<")"<< endl;
        return wyjscie;
    }
```

so to print it I have to use `cout<<*objectOfClassPara<<endl;` otherwise I will print 
address but I can't do it for `string`.

How to correct this code udner?

```
T t = n->key;
            //cout<<n->key<<endl;
            cout<<t<<endl;
            if (is_same<T, Para*>::value){
                cout<<*t<<endl; //IILEGAL INDIRECTION
            }
```

Comment: `t` isn't a pointer, so why would you dereference it?

Comment: @0x499602D2 because it sometimes is.. under it we have `Para* variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `if` is a *runtime* if check, and all possible types have to compile, regardless of whether the code could actually ever execute. So when `T` is `string`, the `*` causes the code to fail.

The simplest solution is to provide an overloaded `operator<<` that works with pointers and remove the `*`:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &wyjscie, Para const* ex)
{
    return wyjscie << *ex;
}
```

Comment: Great, that works! Somebody said me few years ago that it cannot be done.

Comment: Could you look at it please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291060/how-to-make-an-overload-operator-which-works-with-pointers

Answer (score 1):

```
T t
```

Is not a pointer, as 0x499602D2 mentions..

```
T* t
```

Is a pointer, and can be dereferenced like `cout<<*t<<endl;` Template parameters need to be *types*, and a *pointer-to-type* is not valid.