# How to make an overload operator which works with pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As in the subject I need operator which will work with pointers so I do not have to call `*a>*b` but `a>b`.
For example my operator `<<` works with the pointers ok:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &wyjscie, Para const* ex){
    wyjscie << "(" << ex->wrt << ", " << ex->liczbaWystapien <<")"<< endl;
    return wyjscie;
}
```

but this one give me an error:

```
friend bool operator> (Para const *p1, Para const *p2){
        return p1->wrt > p2->wrt;
}
```

---

```
Error   1   error C2803: 'operator >' must have at least one formal parameter of class type
```

Comment: Is the error message not clear?

Comment: Why do you have pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to overload an operator with two pointer values.  This has to do with the ambiguity of such an overloaded operator.

However, you can do this with references instead - but you'd still need to use the `*` operator if you want to keep pointers:

```
friend bool operator> (Para const &p1, Para const &p2){
    return p1.wrt > p2.wrt;
}
```

Comment: I have it like that but the problem is once template class gets string as T and the other time it gets Para* as T and then > is not comparing right thigs

Answer (score 1):

Your overloaded << works because it is being called on an ostream object (ostream.operator<<()).

The pointer overload of operator < does not work because a pointer is not a class so the following is meaningless: (const Para*).operator<().